# Frameworks being used with ASP.NET MVC 3 for TDD?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, tdd, nunit

What are the most popular frameworks being used with ASP.NET MVC 3 for TDD?  What are you using?  Why'd you choose one over the other?

I've worked with Pex/Moles, I've heard of NUnit what else is out there?  What else is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use **[xUnit](http://xunit.codeplex.com/) + [Nsubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.com) + [FluentAssertions](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/)**. Combination of those provides very clean and expressive syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Machine.Fakes](https://github.com/BjRo/Machine.Fakes) on top of [MSpec](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications) because of its simple usage. It is has support for Resharper test runner and is supported by NCrunch.

Update:
In addition there's also [machine.specifications.mvc](https://github.com/jamesbroome/Machine.Specifications.Mvc) built on top of MSpec.

Comment: Thought you were giving me a list of your favorite cereals at first, quick glance: Machine.Flakes, CaptainNCrunch.  Ty for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Strongly recommend the [MvcConribg TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper) which is open source and can be found on [nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/MvcContrib.Mvc3.TestHelper-ci)